# How can you dynamic tenant id in single database using Lumen

Tags: php, sql, laravel, lumen

I am using Lumen API with pgsql in single database with multiple tenant IDs.I am using scope function in model.php and using this function  `checkTenantid()` in all queries. It's working fine, but I don't want to use this function with every query. Can any one suggest me how can I use single function.

```
/** Check Tenant ID is exist or not  **/
public function scopeCheckTenantid( $query, int $tenantid )
{   
    return $query->where('tenantid', '=', $tenantid);
}
```

PatientDataController

```
/* Get single entry of  Heard About, Patient Status and Active Status */

public function get($patientId)
{
    $record =  $this->db
                    ->checkTenantid($this->user->Tenantid)                
                    ->checkPatient($patientId)
                    ->get();

    return $record;
}
```

Thanks

If any query regarding question, please comment me.

Comment: you mean like a Global Scope? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#global-scopes

Comment: Yes, can you help me.

Comment: How do you register the scope?

Comment: how is this statement achieved "using this function checkTenantid() in all queries"